# jquery mobile not navigate after remove and append to body

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile application with phoneGap and it has simple page inside.After user click on button it loads new page from the server witch is out side.So instead of call changepage i used ajax for load page from the server and then append it to body.When user done with it and go back i remove that page from body.But if user click that button again it must reload that content again(it is that much dynamic content) from the server and append to body and navigage.
In my program first time is ok but second time it loads content but doesn't work changepage to that page(i check the body html and the page is there ).

ajax load and appne source :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: pageUrl,
        success: function (result) {
            // alert(result);

            $("body").append(result);
             //alert($("body").html());
            $.mobile.initializePage();


            $.mobile.changePage("#pageloaded",
                { transition: "slide", showLoadMsg: true, changeHash: true });
            alert("done");
        }
    });
```

when user going back:

```
$("#pageloaded").remove();
alert("removed");
```

server page :

```
<div data-role="page"  id="pageloaded"><div data-role="header"><h1>Head</h1></div><div data-role="content">Content</div><div data-role="footer"><h4>Foot</h4></div></div>
```

alerts confirms that all went successfully but on second load it does not navigate and stay on current page.

What is the problem here? any help really appreciate. 
**Note: jquery mobile version 1.0**

Comment: See this example http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/bcz5P/, I have created a similar fiddle for you and its working fine. The problem might be somewhere else in your code

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.But i am using version 1.0.However 1.3 works fine and change project to use 1.3 and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for using `jquery mobile 1.0` is the application was developed using that version some times ago and i had to change so many thing to do so.But at last i had no solutions other than it,so i went for `jquery mobile 1.3.1` and it solved the problem(i have no idea what is the reason).